# XSL Sequence Assignment with Varying Output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In a simplified - highly fabricated - example let's say I have a source document with a bunch of disparate nodes like:

```
<Root>
    <Parent> <!-- potential repeater -->
        <Pelican>
            <NumberOfLegs>2</NumberOfLegs>
        </Pelican>
        <PoorlyBuiltTable>
            <NumberOfLegs>3</NumberOfLegs>
        </PoorlyBuiltTable>
        <Box />
    </Parent>
</Root>
```

and I needed output XML like:

```
<Root>
    <Parent>
        <Thing id="1" Seq="1" />
        <Thing id="1" Seq="2" />
        <Thing id="2" Seq="3" />
        <Thing id="2" Seq="4" />
        <Thing id="2" Seq="5" />
        <Thing id="3" Seq="6" />
    </Parent>
</Root>
```

Such that I need the `id` to be able to be generated to match the disparate node from the source and the `Seq` to be assigned to `Thing` at the scope of `Parent` (that is, `id` and `Seq` can repeat if `Parent` has a sibling with similar children).

Is there a better solution than a two-pass approach of using one style sheet with a recursive loop `template` to generate all my `Thing` instances and then a second - subsequent - style sheet using `preceding-sibling` to generate all my `Seq` attributes?

Comment: I see no reason why a single recursive template couldn't do both. However, you need to clarify the logic here, since the `NotThing` in your example has no original id and no legs. You show 3 legs --> 3 things, 2 legs --> 2 things, 0 legs --> 1 thing, which is puzzling. And what should happen if there were another `Thing' following, with id = 3?

Comment: fantastic comments and i appreciate your help. in an attempt to make the problem simpler i've likely made it more difficult for folks to solve. i've updated my example and preamble -- and thank you again for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of sanity, let me rewrite your input as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <parent id="1">
        <plural>
            <quantity>2</quantity>
        </plural>
        <plural>
            <quantity>3</quantity>
        </plural>
        <singular/>
        <singular/>
        <plural>
            <quantity>2</quantity>
        </plural>
        <singular/>
    </parent>
    <parent id="2">
        <plural>
            <quantity>3</quantity>
        </plural>
        <singular/>
        <plural>
            <quantity>2</quantity>
        </plural>
        <singular/>
    </parent>
</root>
```

Now, applying the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
<result>
    <xsl:for-each select="parent">
    <group parent="{@id}">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:call-template name="gen">
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="start" 
                            select="sum(preceding-sibling::*[quantity>0]/quantity)
                                  + count(preceding-sibling::*[not(quantity>0)])"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="n">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="quantity>0">
                        <xsl:value-of select="quantity" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="1" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </group>
    </xsl:for-each>
</result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="gen">
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <xsl:param name="start"/>
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$i > $n"/>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <item id="{$id}" Seq="{$start+$i}" />
        <xsl:call-template name="gen">
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
  <group parent="1">
    <item id="1" Seq="1"/>
    <item id="1" Seq="2"/>
    <item id="2" Seq="3"/>
    <item id="2" Seq="4"/>
    <item id="2" Seq="5"/>
    <item id="3" Seq="6"/>
    <item id="4" Seq="7"/>
    <item id="5" Seq="8"/>
    <item id="5" Seq="9"/>
    <item id="6" Seq="10"/>
  </group>
  <group parent="2">
    <item id="1" Seq="1"/>
    <item id="1" Seq="2"/>
    <item id="1" Seq="3"/>
    <item id="2" Seq="4"/>
    <item id="3" Seq="5"/>
    <item id="3" Seq="6"/>
    <item id="4" Seq="7"/>
  </group>
</result>
```

Comment: while i'm not a huge fan of the sass (viz - "interest of sanity") i'm going to mark this as the "accepted" answer. though note i'll only be able to uses pieces of the answer in my solution.

Comment: The sanity in question is my own. I just couldn't think of the problem in the way you presented it. It's not unusual to restate the problem as a solving tool. It doesn't reflect on you in any way. Regarding the pieces you don't need: as I explained, I needed them for testing. I thought it would be useful to leave them in, so you (or others) can test the process with a variety of input and follow the steps. Once you have assured yourself that it works, you can "remove the scaffolding" yourself.

Comment: fair enough and i appreciate the additional notes. i recant my original note and again thank you for your help.